# FFMpeg is not working to generate thumbnail but it converts mp4 to mp3

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg and path is correct, because when i go to convert mp4 video to mp3, it works. here is its code.

`shell_exec('/home/pakunit/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i newfile.mp4 output4.mp3');`

even this code is also works for cut a video from mp4 to mp4 using this code

```
shell_exec("/home/pakunit/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i newfile.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4");
```

and when I use mostly other commands, no command works, Like i want to create video thumbnail and i am using this code.

```
shell_exec("/home/pakunit/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i newfile.mp4 -an -ss 5 -s 120x90 thumbnail.jpg")
```

but its not working. also i tried many codes and command for creating thumbnail, but not working any of them. even i used the exact same command that is on ffmpeg.org original website

```
shell_exec("/home/pakunit/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i newfile.mp4 -vf thumbnail,scale=300:200 -frames:v 1 out.png");
```

Is any extension missed in hosting? or any special extension or module we need to enable from hosting? there is also ffmpeg enabled in PHP extension, but not showing in phpinfo(); Please help. thanks

Comment: Share full ffmpeg log of failing command.

Comment: there is not log file created. just nothing happened.

Comment: Is any method to check if ffmpeg is correctly installed with all modules and extension from php script?